# Split a 3-variable equation into doubles and characters in C++

Tags: c++, parsing, equation

I'm working on an assignment with equations, but I can't figure out how to input the different parts of the equation.

The equation is always formatted: 
[double][x/y/z][sign][double][x/y/z][sign][double][x/y/z]=[double].

An example: 2.5y+4.7x+7z=46

To accomplish this, I tried using four double variables and six character variables.

double a,d,g,j;

char b,c,e,f,h,i;

so that the equation splits into the variables a b c d e f g h i, which I can then manipulate.

If there were whitespaces anywhere in the equation, I could have used istringstream to split them, but there aren't. I am not allowed to change the input file.

How can I put the numbers in doubles, and the letters/symbols in characters?

Comment: Where's the code? What's the error you got? Did you tried?

Comment: My problem is I don't even know where to start. I tried using an istringstream only to find out that it splits on spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use istringstream and out of stream operator. 
For example:

```
std::istringstream iss("2.5y+4.7x+7z=46");
double a,b,c,s;
char v1,v2,v3;
iss >> a; // read 1st koef
iss >> v1; // read 1st var's name 
iss >> b; // read 2nd koef
iss >> v2; // read 2nd var's name
iss >> c; // read 3rd koef
iss >> v3; // read 3rd var's name
iss.ignore(); // skip '=' symbol
iss >> s; // read sum
```

Signs in equation is sign of relevant koefs.

Comment: The `ignore` won't work properly if there is whitespace in the input before the `=` (the OP is unclear as to whether there is never whitespace or sometimes whitespace).  Better off reading it into a `char` and then ignoring it.

Comment: This is similar to what I attempted, but it appears (unless I was wrong) that the delimiter for istringstream is whitespace, of which there is none in the input. Is there an alternative which does something similar?

Comment: @EmilyEvelan: whitespace is only a delimiter for reading into `std::string` or `char *` variables -- for `double` and `char`, leading whitespace is ignored but does not delimit anything.  The only real problem with this approach is that if you have a variable `e` or `E` it will be incorrectly treated as an exponent on the double.

Comment: In that case, I was wrong, and istringstream will indeed work, or should. I have no whitespaces anywhere in the equation, only coefficients, plus/minus, the variables (x,y,z), the equal sign, and the sum.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, the author specified the format [double][x/y/z][sign][double][x/y/z][sign][double][x/y/z]=[double]

Comment: @DmitriyKhaustov I have no idea why my code did not work, but yours did. I was bottled necked by that problem, and now I can continue my assignment. Thank you!